# Curl request exits at five minutes unexpectedly

Tags: curl, timeout

I'm using a shell script to fire off a curl request that deletes all documents of a certain type in my Elasticsearch cluster.  If successful, Logstash starts and attempts to reindex the deleted type's documents.

```
printf "\n%s\n" "Sending delete request..."

RESPONSE=$(curl --max-time 600 -XPOST 
"https://mycluster.com:9243/locations/ca/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed" -H 
'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "query": { "match_all": {} } }' 
--user user:password)

if [[ $RESPONSE == *"deleted"* ]]; then
  echo $RESPONSE
  printf "\n%s\n" "Delete successful, starting Logstash..."
  cd /home/denroot/EP-logstash && bin/logstash -f /home/denroot/EP-
  logstash-configs/locations/create/california.config
else
  echo $RESPONSE
  printf "\n%s\n" "Delete failed, shutting down..."
fi
```

The issue I've encountered is this particular type has over 5 million documents.  The Elasticsearch delete task cannot finish before 5 minutes have elapsed, and my curl request exits with an exit code of 0.  I can't seem to prevent this from happening with --max-time.  Normally, when the delete task finishes in Elasticsearch, it sends back a JSON response body which I need for my control-flow logic to work properly.  Any help preventing this 5 minute exit issue would be greatly appreciated as I can't seem to find a precedent.

Comment: Can you rework the logic to delete only a few (tens of) thousand documents at a time, and work at it in smaller bites?

Comment: Exit code 0. So `curl` thinks the request is complete. What HTTP status do you get back?

Comment: When curl exits, the value of `$RESPONSE` is empty.

Comment: `curl` would return exit code 0 even on a 4xx HTTP error. Try runing your `curl` command with `-I` to view the status code returned by the server and other HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

Your script should exit after 10 minutes as it is.

Try increasing (or removing) max-time for lifting that limit

If the 5 minutes timeout is imposed on server side, you could try running the curl command multiple times until you receive the expected output/exit code.

Comment: You may be onto something that the timeout is imposed server-side.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any documentation in the Elasticsearch delete-by-query API about response timeouts.  Thank you anyway!